# how to use lambda inside a function

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I am trying to create a function to perform operations with columns of a data frame, but in the end it gives me an error because when defining the lambda x: x.variable, variable takes it literally, how do I assign the value it has? variable in the x.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

def example(dataFrame, variable):
  dataFrame= dataFrame.assign(newColumn= lambda x: x.variable**2)
example(df,'col1')
```

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'variable'

How can i fix this?

Comment: Not sure, but I think you can use `x[variable]` instead.

Comment: BTW, this has *nothing* to do with functions, lambda expressions, etc. This is how it would work in *any* situation, if you do `foo.variable`, it tries to access the `variable` attribute on the object, it doesn't interpolate a string into the source code

Comment: For pandas data structures in particular, you can just sue `foo[variable]`, indeed, this is the way it is always preferred to access on a pandas data structure. In general, if you have some string, `variable = "something"`, and you want to access an attirbute named the same as that string value, you can use `getattr(foo, variable)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the x.variable to x[variable] inside your lambda

```
def example(dataFrame, variable):
    dataFrame = dataFrame.assign(newColumn = lambda x: x[variable]**2)
    return dataFrame # you probably want to return the dataFrame as well

example(df,'col1')
```

df.column_name (x.variable) can be used only if the column already exists, in your case you are creating a new column and the property you are calling does not exist on that dataframe yet. So you can use df['new column name'] (x[variable])